# "Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely" in Extjs 4

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-8, ext.net

I'm getting this in my [internet-explorer-8](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-8):

**"Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely" in Extjs 4**

How to handle this in [internet-explorer-8](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-8) with Code and still keep my application secured. 
I am updating my application with ext.net V 2 here.

Comment: Sounds like some content is fetched over SSL and some is not...? Isn't all content available over SSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been introduced in ExtJS 4.2.0 and automatically came to Ext.NET v2.2. It is fixed in ExtJS 4.2.1 and, accordingly, will be fixed in the next Ext.NET v2.3 release, which should appear soon.

Here you can find some details about the bug and thoughts about a possible solution.

**[Check reference 1](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?261165&p=960993&viewfull=1#post960993)**

**[Check reference 2](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?259626&p=962375&viewfull=1#post962375)**